# The physical implementation of quantum annealing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

From [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194552/what-is-the-difference-between-quantum-annealing-and-simulated-annealing) question about differences between Quantum annealing and simulated annealing, we found (in comments to answer) that physical implementation of quantum annealing exists (D-Wave quantum computers).

Can anyone explain that algorithm in terms of quantum gates and quantum algorithms, or in physical terms (a part of algorithm that depends on quantum hardware)?

Comment: Possibly more suited to: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

This question should probably go to physics.SE but just as a warning: The D-Wave quantum computer might not really give any speed advancement, because.. something is wrong. So there might not be any physical implementation available so far.

See: *Quantum or not, controversial computer yields no speedup*, Adrian Cho, Science, 20, 2014, [Link](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/344/6190/1330.summary)

Answer (score -3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_annealing):

> Quantum annealing can be compared to simulated annealing (SA), whose
>   "temperature" parameter plays a similar role to QA's tunneling field
>   strength. However, in SA the neighborhood stays the same throughout
>   the search, and the temperature determines the probability of moving
>   to a state of higher "energy". In QA, the tunneling field strength
>   determines instead the neighborhood radius, i.e. the mean distance
>   between the next candidate state and the current candidate state.

In other words, the "tunneling field" and, indeed, the term "quantum" are just metaphors for the finer points of a completely classical (although randomized) algorithm. QA is not inherently connected with actual quantum computers, it just borrows terms from physics to make a point about computational properties.

Comment: From another question we found that physical implementation of quantum annealing exists (D-Wave quantum computers). I talking about physical implementation, not about metaphors.